# How to open an application from a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I am developing a Flutter app, in which I need to show navigation to the user for a place. So, how can I open a map application from my Flutter app like we do using external intent in Android?

Or their is any flutter-plugin for it?

Comment: take a look: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

Answer (score 78, accepted):

I suggest you to use [url_launcher](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) dart package.

In this way you can use all url schemas to open (`phone`, `sms`, and even `maps` as in your case).

In order to open Google Maps either in Android and iOS you could use the [general Android Maps URI schema](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) as suggested by Hemanth Raj.

```or-tag-here
_openMap() async {
    const url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=52.32,4.917';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

If you want to give a choice on Android you could use the general [`geo:` URI schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI_scheme).

If you want specifically open iOS Maps API you can use [Cupertino Maps URI schema](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH5-SW1).

If you choose to distinguish between Android and iOS (not using Google Maps Api schema for all platform) you have to do it also in your open map call in a way like this:

```or-tag-here
_openMap() async {
    // Android
    const url = 'geo:52.32,4.917';
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      // iOS
      const url = 'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=52.32,4.917';
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }
  }
```

Or you can check the OS at runtime with [`dart.io` library `Platform` class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Platform-class.html):

```or-tag-here
import 'dart:io';

_openMap() async {
    // Android
    var url = 'geo:52.32,4.917';
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      // iOS
      url = 'http://maps.apple.com/?ll=52.32,4.917';
    }
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
```

Now that I finished hosekeeping (the real one... not some code refactoring... ^^') I can finish my answer.

As I tell you at the beginning with url_launcher you can use all URI Schemas in order to call, send sms, send e-mail etc.

Here some code to do that:

```or-tag-here
_sendMail() async {
    // Android and iOS
    const uri = 'mailto:test@example.org?subject=Greetings&body=Hello%20World';
    if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
      await launch(uri);
    } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $uri';
    }
  }

  _callMe() async {
    // Android
    const uri = 'tel:+1 222 060 888';
    if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
      await launch(uri);
    } else {
      // iOS
      const uri = 'tel:001-22-060-888';
      if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
        await launch(uri);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $uri';
      }
    }
  }

  _textMe() async {
    // Android
    const uri = 'sms:+39 349 060 888';
    if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
      await launch(uri);
    } else {
      // iOS
      const uri = 'sms:0039-222-060-888';
      if (await canLaunch(uri)) {
        await launch(uri);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $uri';
      }
    }
  }
```

Even if [URI](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) schema should be standards (RFC) sometimes the `authority` and `path` parts of them could differ between frameworks (Android or iOS).

So here I manage the different OSes with exception but, you could do it better with [`dart.io` library `Platform` class](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/Platform-class.html):

```or-tag-here
import 'dart:io'
```

and then in code:

```or-tag-here
if (Platform.isAndroid) {

} else if (Platform.isIOS) {

}
```

I suggest you always test them in both environments.

You can check the Android and iOS schema documenation here:

- [Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html)
- [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1)

If you wanna something similar to startActivity in Android (but that works only for Android platform) you can use the dart package [android_intent](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_intent).

Comment: Wooow...that's a great answer. and +1 for the housekeeping part :)

Comment: Nice explanation. This may be a whole different question, but I want to ask if it is possible to open my own application using url_launcher from my flutter application?

Comment: @RanaRanvijaySingh Actually i didn't try myself yet, but maybe you could give it a try with [app or deep link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)/[universal link](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) and once set'em up for your other (own/native? I hope I actually got what you were intending) application you could try to pass these on url_launcher.

Comment: @RanaRanvijaySingh I've just tried with Firebase Dynamic Links ('cause I had already two native applications using them) and I can confirm that this scenario is working as expected on my devices. With a flutter application calling `launch(<dynamic link>)` my native application are launched.

Comment: Thanks, @shadowsheep. I went another way as I had to pass some data back to calling application. Here is the link if you are interested. https://medium.com/@ranaranvijaysingh9/share-data-between-two-applications-flutter-and-android-1bb6e2573103

Comment: what about email? Is possible to open the default email client using something similar to this?

Comment: how to resume opened app?

Answer (score 17):

For iOS use, no browser involved, directly to apps:

```
//waze 
canLaunch("waze://") 
launch("waze://?ll=${latitude},${longitude}&navigate=yes"); 
//gmaps 
canLaunch("comgooglemaps://") 
launch("comgooglemaps://?saddr=${latitude},${longitude}&directionsmode=driving")
```

What you need to do is to add to Info.plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>  
<array>         
  <string>comgooglemaps</string>        
  <string>waze</string>     
</array>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the [`url_launcher`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher) plugin to open maps. It launches map if installed or falls back to open the map on a browser.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new Scaffold(
    body: new Center(
      child: new RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: new Text('Launch Maps'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchMaps() async {
  const url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,17&query_place_id=PLACE_ID";
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch Maps';
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a scenario where you want to open device installed app from Flutter?

If so , you can use a package called device_apps.

This FLutter package also shows you icon of app to display and you can open app by package name as well.

Just browse all methods it offers. I am using it for my Flutter FItness app to launch installed music player.

https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps

Comment: thank you for suggesting this package. this solved my another problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In that case you just need to use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) plugin which opens your app.

```
yourMap() async {
  const url = "https://www.google.com/maps/search/? 
  api=1&query=LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,17&query_place_id=PLACE_ID";
 if (await canLaunch(url)) {
   await launch(url);
 } else {
   throw 'Could not launch Maps';
  }
}
```

and then call this yourMap() method on your button onPress.

Answer (score 0):

**The url_launcher plugin allows your Flutter application to perform actions like opening a web page in Safari or deep-linking into another application with context.**

**Adding the url_launcher Plugin**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  url_launcher: ^6.0.3


import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'URL Launcher',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'URL Launcher'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void>? _launched;
  String _phone = '';

  Future<void> _launchInBrowser(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: false,
        forceWebView: false,
        headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'},
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  Future<void> _launchInWebViewOrVC(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: true,
        forceWebView: true,
        headers: <String, String>{'my_header_key': 'my_header_value'},
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  Future<void> _launchInWebViewWithJavaScript(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: true,
        forceWebView: true,
        enableJavaScript: true,
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  Future<void> _launchInWebViewWithDomStorage(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: true,
        forceWebView: true,
        enableDomStorage: true,
      );
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  Future<void> _launchUniversalLinkIos(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      final bool nativeAppLaunchSucceeded = await launch(
        url,
        forceSafariVC: false,
        universalLinksOnly: true,
      );
      if (!nativeAppLaunchSucceeded) {
        await launch(
          url,
          forceSafariVC: true,
        );
      }
    }
  }

  Widget _launchStatus(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<void> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    } else {
      return const Text('');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _makePhoneCall(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const String toLaunch = 'https:'https://www.cylog.org/headers/';
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Text('Launch URL : $toLaunch'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _launchInBrowser(toLaunch);
                }),
                child: const Text('Launch in browser'),
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _launchInWebViewOrVC(toLaunch);
                }),
                child: const Text('Launch in app'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _launchInWebViewWithJavaScript(toLaunch);
                }),
                child: const Text('Launch in app(JavaScript ON)'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _launchInWebViewWithDomStorage(toLaunch);
                }),
                child: const Text('Launch in app(DOM storage ON)'),
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _launchUniversalLinkIos(toLaunch);
                }),
                child: const Text(
                    'Launch a universal link in a native app, fallback to Safari.(Youtube)'),
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () => setState(() {
                  _launched = _launchInWebViewOrVC(toLaunch);
                  Timer(const Duration(seconds: 5), () {
                    print('Closing WebView after 5 seconds...');
                    closeWebView();
                  });
                }),
                child: const Text('Launch in app + close after 5 seconds'),
              ),
              const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0)),
              FutureBuilder<void>(future: _launched, builder: _launchStatus),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```