# How can a flutter application send and receive data from other applications

Tags: flutter

How do I send and receive data from a flutter application to another Android or iOS application (which may also be another flutter application)?
All the applications are on the same phone.

Flutter app ----data---> Other application 
Other application ----data--> Flutter app

Comment: what kind of data do you want to send? Is it necessary to go straight from app to app, or is it ok also if it goes online?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to send private data which cannot be shared over the network. And it should be from app to app without going online.

Comment: I think you will have to utilize `PlatformChannels` with https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/communicating_with_other_apps_using_custom_urls

Comment: I think there is one url_launcher plugin that you can utilize. I dont know if it supports app to app urls, but you can exapnd on it

Comment: Hey, did you find any way to achieve this without using native code?

Answer (score 5):

Currently what you have is:

for Android:

- [receive intents in flutter](https://flutter.io/flutter-for-android/#how-do-i-handle-incoming-intents-from-external-applications-in-flutter)

for Both:

1. [using url launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49346421/9882060)
2. [share intents](https://github.com/d-silveira/flutter-share.git)