# Flutter: how to let a file be opened by an external app (like Android's implicit intent)?

Tags: android, flutter

I am building a Flutter app that essentially fetches data from the cloud. 
The data type varies, but they're commonly an image, pdf, text file, or an archive (zip file).

Now I want to fire an implicit intent, so the user can choose their favorite app to handle the payload.

I've searched for answers, and I have tried the following routes:

1. url_launcher plugin (as suggested in [How to open an application from a Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345605/how-to-open-an-application-from-a-flutter-app))
2. android intent
3. share plugin

Route #3 is not really what I wanted, since it's using the platform's "share" mechanism (ie. posting on Twitter / send to contact), instead of opening the payload.

Route 1 & 2 sort of worked... in a shaky, weird way. I'll explain later.

Here's the flow of my code:

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

// ...
// retrieve payload from internet and save it to an External Storage location
File payload = await getPayload();
String uriToShare = samplePayload.uri.toString();

// at this point uriToShare looks like: 'file:///storage/emulated/0/jpg_example.jpg'
uriToShare = uriToShare.replaceFirst("file://", "content://");

// launch url    
if (await canLaunch(uriToShare)) {
  await launch(uriToShare);
} else {
  throw "Failed to launch $uriToShare";
```

the above code was using `url_launcher` plugin. If I was using `android_intent` plugin, then the last lines of code becomes:

```
// fire intent 
AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
  action: "action_view",
  data: uriToShare,
);
await intent.launch();
```

Everything up to saving the file to external directory works (I can confirm that the files exist after running the code)

Things get weird when I try to share the URI. 
I have tested this piece of code on 3 different phones. One of them (Samsung Galaxy S9) would throw this exception:

```
I/io.flutter.plugins.androidintent.AndroidIntentPlugin(10312): Sending intent Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content:///storage/emulated/0/jpg_example.jpg }
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content:///storage/emulated/0/jpg_example.jpg cmp=com.google.android.gm/.browse.TrampolineActivity } from ProcessRecord{6da6f74 10312:com.safe.fmeexpress/u0a218} (pid=10312, uid=10218) requires com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1959)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1905)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4886)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1617)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4564)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4522)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4883)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4851)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at io.flutter.plugins.androidintent.AndroidIntentPlugin.onMethodCall(AndroidIntentPlugin.java:141)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:191)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterNativeView.java:152)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/android_intent(10312):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I have no idea how the intent got polluted by `cmp=com.google.android.gm/.browse.TrampolineActivity`

This exception ONLY happens in Galaxy S9. 
Two other phones did not give me this problem. 
They did launch the file uri, and I was asked how to open the file, but none of the image-handling apps were being offered (ie, like Gallery, QuickPic, or Google Photos).

Just to clarify, both `url_launcher` and `android_intent` routes lead to the exact same results.

It feels like I'm missing a step here. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? Do I have to start using platform channels to accomplish this?

Some clarifications on why I did what I did:

- Converted uri type from file:// to content:// because I was getting `android.os.FileUriExposedException`
- Stored temporary file in external storage because I don't want to deal with granting URI READ PERMISSION just yet. (I tried, but `android_intent` doesn't have a way to set intent flags just yet)

Comment: Use this plugin : https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's hard to get this to work correctly. Here are some hints that helped me to launch `ACTION_VIEW` intents from Flutter, with files downloaded with Flutter.

1) Register a `FileProvider` in the android manifest:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.example.myapp.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

`provider_paths.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
        <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    </paths>
```

2) Create a custom platform channel that provides 2 methods (Code below is Kotlin):

**`getDownloadsDir`**: Should return the data dir where downloaded files should be placed. Try this one:

```
val downloadsDir = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).path
result.success(downloadsDir);
```

**`previewFile`** that takes 2 string arguments: `path` (`File.path` in Dart) and `type` (e.g. "application/pdf"):

```
val file = File(path);
val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.myapp.provider", file);

val viewFileIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
viewFileIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
viewFileIntent.setDataAndType(uri, type);
try {
  startActivity(viewFileIntent);
  result.success(null);
} catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
  result.error(...);
}
```

The most important part is the creation of the `FileProvider`. url_launcher and android_intent will not work, you have to create your own platform channel. You can change the download path, but then you also have to find the correct provider/permissions settings.

Making this work on iOS is also possible, but out of scope of this question.

---

If you are using the image_picker plugin:

The `FileProvider` conflicts with the current version of the image_picker (0.4.6) plugin, a fix will be released soon.

Comment: You're right. The main issue was that it's become quite tedious to share a file to other apps via intents, regardless of the file's location (doesn't matter if the file resides in the app's local directory or in external, shared directory like "Downloads")

Comment: I just come across this exact requirement in Flutter, I wonder if things have changed a bit now since this question was asked in Aug 2018? Or Platform Channel is still the only way to accomplish this? Cheers.

Comment: This is still the way to go. Maybe there are better plugins now, but those plugins will do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Kagawa did you find any solution for that or the above approach is the only one right now?

Comment: can anyone link an example repo? I am having really hard time figuring this out

Comment: `Undefined name "FileProvider"`

Comment: If file is modified in the external app is it possible for Flutter to pick up the change and e.g. upload new file version back to cloud?

Answer (score 7):

Since this was answered, an excellent flutter plugin [open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) have been published, solving this cross platform.

When coupled with [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) - in the following example downloading into `getTemporaryDirectory()`, this opens a given url/filename with the associated app on iOS and Android (using the local file if already downloaded):

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:open_filex/open_filex.dart';

Future<String> download(String url, String filename) async {
  String dir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
  File file = File('$dir/$filename');
  if (await file.exists()) return file.path;
  await file.create(recursive: true);
  var response = await http.get(url).timeout(Duration(seconds: 60));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
    return file.path;
  }
  throw 'Download ${url} failed';
}

void downloadAndLaunch(String url, String filename) {
  download(url, filename).then((String path) {
    OpenFilex.open(path);
  });
}
```

-- Edit: --
Changed reference from `open_file` to `open_filex`, since the original package requests REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES rights by default on android. This blocks review in Google Play, from september 2022.

Comment: Does this approach support opening 'epub' files - like for Books app( iOS) or Play Books app (Google) to open the files?

Comment: I have only tested this using pdf files, but as long as there is an associated app for it, it should work for all kinds of files, including epub.

Comment: Works for opening PDF files in both Android and iOS.