# Is there a way to open other applications in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to be able open other apps in my flutter application

In an application i am working on I need to be able to play videos however the video_player plugin in flutter only has play and pause options and there is chewie also however we don't have the option of pausing chewie with commands , so I am thinking of opening videos through other apps like vlc,MX players, etc. How do i open these apps in flutter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open an application from a Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345605/how-to-open-an-application-from-a-flutter-app)

Comment: You should google for URI Schema and Deep Linking

Comment: The app should not connect to internet.Is it possible to use Deep linking offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the [`open_file`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/open_file) plugin, it supports opening most of the file including videos.

Example usage:

Specify dependency in `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  open_file: ^1.1.1
```

then

```
import 'package:open_file/open_file.dart';

OpenFile.open(your_file_path);
```

Hope that helps!