# How do I open instagram from flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to transite to Instagram profile, when I am tapping on button. I use this library [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher). But there I can use only Web Browser for this. What will I do, in order to reach my goal?

Comment: Probably the answer is : https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399633/7966313

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't know if it's too late, but this works for me using the url_launcher library (tested on android only):

```
var url = 'https://www.instagram.com/<INSTAGRAM_PROFILE>/';

if (await canLaunch(url)) {
  await launch(
    url,
    universalLinksOnly: true,
  );
} else {
  throw 'There was a problem to open the url: $url';
}
```

Comment: This works, but in the App Store review process we got flagged for "Your app includes Google Play references in the page when we tap Instagram. Referencing third-party platforms in your app or it's metadata is not permitted on the App Store unless there is specific interactive functionality". (There is a google logo on the instagram login page. But perhaps we just didn't disclose the functionality enough in the review notes.)

Answer (score 9):

To open Native and WebView Instagram:

1. Add to your iOS/Runner/Info.plist:

   ```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        ...
        <string>instagram</string>
    </array>
   ```
2. Install url_launcher ( https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher )
3. Import

   import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
4. Create some method like this;

Inside Widget for example:

```
  _launchInstagram() async {
    const nativeUrl = "instagram://user?username=severinas_app";
    const webUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/severinas_app/";
    if (await canLaunch(nativeUrl)) {
      await launch(nativeUrl);
    } else if (await canLaunch(webUrl)) {
      await launch(webUrl);
    } else {
      print("can't open Instagram");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

2022 update:

```
 _launchInstagram() async {
    var nativeUrl = "instagram://user?username=balkan.exe";
    var webUrl = "https://www.instagram.com/balkan.exe";

    try {
      await launchUrlString(nativeUrl, mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      await launchUrlString(webUrl, mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Install url_launcher ( https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher )
2. They now have a mode parameter, which you set to LaunchMode.externalApplication;
3. Call it with the regular https url, if they have the app installed it will open the app, otherwise it will open in Safari. Don't worry about doing an app link and a website url, the package and the OS handle it accordingly.

For example, here are my links in our About section of the app to our socials..

```
SettingsListTileModel(
// This can be any website's url that has a corresponding app, we us it with Twitter, Facebook, Instagram, and Youtube.
                onTap: () => launchUrl(
                    Uri.parse('https://www.instagram.com/forwheel_app/'),
                    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
                ),
                title: Text(
                  'Instagram',
                  style: context.bodyLarge),
                ),
                trailing: Icon(
                  FontAwesomeIcons.squareArrowUpRight,
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can launch the profile activity, unless you know the name (which might change in the future). But, if you can try launching the app by using Intent plugin:

Try adding the Intent plugin: 
https://pub.dev/packages/intent

Add intent in you in your pubspec.yaml file.

You can call the specific app with the package name (in this case Instagram).

```
Intent()
    ..setAction(Action.ACTION_SHOW_APP_INFO)
    ..putExtra(Extra.EXTRA_PACKAGE_NAME, "instagram package name")
    ..startActivity().catchError((e) => print(e));
```

You can also make use Android flutter plugin for Intent: 
https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent

This will support for Android : 
Use it by specifying action, category, data and extra arguments for the intent. It does not support returning the result of the launched activity

For IOS url_launcher plugin can be used for deep linking

Answer (score 0):

You can create a platform channel and use the intent to achieve that or use social_share package.