# How do I redirect user to Instagram App instead of opening their browser in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, instagram-api, facebook-oauth

I am integrating connect using Instagram feature in Flutter. Currently Flutter only allow users to open the Instagram using their mobile browser instead of opening the app.

The flutter launch url behavior can only choose to launch in app web view / external browser. Below is the code used.

sample link:
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxx (not [www.instagram.com](http://www.instagram.com) as it's for OAuth)

package used: [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

code used:

```dart
launchUrl(
  Uri.parse(igLink),
  mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
);
```

I tried the one mentioned here: [How do I open instagram from flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088044/how-do-i-open-instagram-from-flutter-app)

It only worked for `www.instagram.com` but not when we are using the API.

How can I make it open using instagram for authorization instead of browser?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you should tell your project manager/business analyst that this behavior is super normal in mobile application world :) Or if you want it that way just because u want to improve your app, CONGRATULATION, you would become a great developer!

Comment: Well I think if you want to open with that "oauth" api.instagram.com, you must go through a web view