# How to open an existing android app and send data to it using flutter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, dart

Hello i want to open an existing app(which i also made) i can launch the app from my flutter app using this package flutter_appavailability: ^0.0.21 what i want is to send a data from the flutter app then to the app which i'm opening.

what i want is to send data sample "test data" to the one textbox in the app which i'm opening.

bellow is my current code in opening my existing app.

```
   home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Plugin flutter_appavailability app'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: installedApps == null ? 0 : installedApps.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(installedApps[index]["app_name"]),
              trailing: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.open_in_new),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Scaffold.of(context).hideCurrentSnackBar();
                    AppAvailability.launchApp(installedApps[index]["package_name"]).then((_) {
                      print("App ${installedApps[index]["app_name"]} launched!");
                    }).catchError((err) {
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                          content: Text("App ${installedApps[index]["app_name"]} not found!")
                      ));
                      print(err);
                    });
                  }
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open an application from a Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345605/how-to-open-an-application-from-a-flutter-app)

Comment: My problem is how to receive the data on my 2nd app which i also made