# How to do implicit intent in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to redirect my Flutter app to any other third party apps like Whatsapp, Skype, mail and etc. how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on android you can use [android_intent](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent) package (you must use it only on android or app will crash):

```
if (platform.isAndroid) {
  AndroidIntent intent = AndroidIntent(
      action: 'action_view',
      data: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?'
          'id=com.google.android.apps.myapp',
      arguments: {'authAccount': currentUserEmail},
  );
  await intent.launch();
}
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49345605/9142279).