# Google pay UPI integration in flutter for ios using any sdk which works all over the world

Tags: ios, flutter, google-pay, upi

I am creating an app for google pay UPI. Can anyone suggest me how google pay UPI works for IOS platform in flutter? I didn't find any related code on internet.
Note: Do not want to user razor pay and stipe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use PayTM All in One SDK... here is the [link](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/all-in-one-sdk/hybrid-apps/flutter/?ref=allInOneMerchantIntegration) for your reference.

Comment: I need to use Google pay . Not PayTM or any other payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Flutter, but if you do the equivalent of building UPI URI and launching an intent to the URI, that should hopefully work.

[Example of how to build the URI in Java](https://developers.google.com/pay/india/api/android/in-app-payments):

```java
String GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.nbu.paisa.user";
int GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE = 123;

Uri uri =
    new Uri.Builder()
        .scheme("upi")
        .authority("pay")
        .appendQueryParameter("pa", "your-merchant-vpa@xxx")
        .appendQueryParameter("pn", "your-merchant-name")
        .appendQueryParameter("mc", "your-merchant-code")
        .appendQueryParameter("tr", "your-transaction-ref-id")
        .appendQueryParameter("tn", "your-transaction-note")
        .appendQueryParameter("am", "your-order-amount")
        .appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR")
        .appendQueryParameter("url", "your-transaction-url")
        .build();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, GOOGLE_PAY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

If you don't care about which app is used to handle the UPI request, remove `intent.setPackage(GOOGLE_PAY_PACKAGE_NAME);`

Comment: This can be work for android , but i am looking for IOS.

Comment: Can you use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345605/how-to-open-an-application-from-a-flutter-app using the URI from the code above?